# How to "extract aside" an element from a vertical flexbox layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Let's say I have a couple elements arranged in a column (using flexbox):
[image: elements in a column]

And I would like to "spotlight" element #2 in green and set it aside, but let the rest of the elements remain ordered in a column:

[image: a wider layout, with element #2 set aside]

Is there a way to do this with just CSS and retain dynamic layout?

I've thought of a workaround by duplicating the green element and wrapping all of this in another flexbox layout (`[2[1234]]`) so that in the column case, the first green element is hidden (`[#[1234]`) whereas in the wider case, the second element is hidden (`[2[1#34]`), but this is a bit messy in the markup - and actually causes issues when the element has some kind of state (e.g. a `<video>`) that is expected to be retained in both cases.

I've also thought about using `position: absolute` on the green element, but I couldn't get that to work nicely either: once I set `position: relative` on the top-level (black) container, I can position the green element where I want, but setting `position: absolute` on the column container (red) so that I can position in to the right means green element is now positioned relative to the column container again.

Is there a solution I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this using just CSS. Here's the code for the answer to your question.
HTML:

```
   <div class="gridcontainer">
   <div class="display">
 
   </div>
   <div class="flexcontainer">
   <div class="card">1</div>
   <div class="card">2</div>
   <div class="card">3</div>
   <div class="card">4</div>
   <div class="card">5</div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.gridcontainer{
    display: grid;
    background: yellow;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr .5fr;
    height: 20em;
    }
    .flexcontainer{
    background: skyblue;
    padding: .5em;
    grid-column: 2;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    }
    .card{
    background: pink;
    border: .1em solid red;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    }
    .flexcontainer .card:hover{
    position: absolute;
    width: 45%;
    height: 15em;
    transform: translateX(-50vw) translateY(1vh);
    }
```

Comment: You have to use both Flexbox and Grid. The grid sets the main divide between the empty space and the content. Then use flex to stack the elements and finally use a CSS position absolute + transform property on the items to they can be removed from the flow of the flexbox and translateX to move them left.. I know it sound complicated but try this code out on code out and you'll see it works fine also try understand all of it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const expand = document.querySelector('.expand');

expand.addEventListener('click', () => {
  expand.parentNode.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

aside {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  transition: .2s;
}

div {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  order: unset;
}

.expand {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px white;
}

.expand svg {
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transition: .2s;
}

aside.active {
  width: 90vw;
}

.active .expand svg {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.active .two {
  flex: 100 0 100%;
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<aside class="aside">
  <button class="expand">
    <svg width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"><path d="M12 0c6.623 0 12 5.377 12 12s-5.377 12-12 12-12-5.377-12-12 5.377-12 12-12zm0 1c6.071 0 11 4.929 11 11s-4.929 11-11 11-11-4.929-11-11 4.929-11 11-11zm-3 5.753l6.44 5.247-6.44 5.263.678.737 7.322-6-7.335-6-.665.753z"/></svg>
  </button>
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
  <div class="thr">3</div>
  <div class="for">4</div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want, i can answer this, but not using flexbox, using Grid.

Comment: It is best to place these kind of comments in the comment section under the question instead of an answer. Or explain you answer how you would fix this using Grid.